Should the salt be used for data-independent memory access in password hashing algorithms?
For password hashing, is it better to compute a pseudorandom data-independent memory access pattern using the salt, the cost parameters (memory size, iterations, and parallelism), or some other way?
Balloon uses the salt, whereas Argon2i uses the cost parameters. I haven't taken the time to look at the other candidates in the Password Hashing Competition as there are a lot (literally a PhD thesis to understand each algorithm).
The advantage of using the salt is that the memory access pattern is unique per user in the database. However, people on the phc-discussions mailing list were critical of this approach, claiming it may leak who logged in, can lead to weak memory access patterns, and a cache-timing attack leaks the salt (which shouldn't be public unnecessarily).
I'm not sure if there are any papers that cover this question. After searching through hundreds of files, that's all the relevant discussion I can find on the mailing list (there are more links/emails, but they say the same thing). The remaining talk/criticism about data-independent access applies regardless of which way you do it.

Edited to add:
The Balloon paper has a relevant open question in section 8:

Is it possible to build hardware that effectively implements the pROM
attacks [3, 4, 5] against Argon2i and Balloon at realistic parameter
sizes? What efficiency gain would this pROM hardware have over a
sequential ASIC at attacking these constructions? Are these parallel
attacks still practical in hardware when the function’s memory-access
pattern depends on the salt (as Balloon’s access pattern does)?


Doesn't Argon team advise Argon2id to mitigate all?

@kelalaka Yes, they recommend Argon2id. However, a hybrid mode doesn't resist side-channel attacks as well as a fully data-independent mode, and the question is still relevant for a hybrid mode.

This is a complex question to answer, since there are so many details and design choices to analyze. For that reason I'll only consider what seem to me to be strongest choices and give an explanation as to why.

The possibility of a weak visitation pattern shouldn't be a concern if the internals of the hashing algorithm are good: If there ample internal states to visit (good), with each holding sufficient uniquely work-memory-dependent information (good), that is mixed with other states securely (good), where a sufficient number of selections are chosen from that space (good), and the pattern is chosen with adequate unpredictable (better) randomization (good) — then the likelihood of a bad visitation pattern would be vanishingly small.

Each application has context information which is both (reasonably) static and public. From the name of the service and their public certificate, to their creation date and public URL, there are ample context strings to include which can make the work of each attack unique to each service if a visitation pattern is derived from only public information. Aside from the visitation pattern, it'd also be a good idea to include all of this public context information in the initial hashing together of the password, salt, and cost parameters. That would make the internal secret also dependent on the context, not just the final result.

The cost parameters could also be safely assumed to be public. Services tend to all pick from well-promoted and suggested least, middle, and most expensive configurations, so they're not generally secret. If a service uses a super bespoke set of cost parameters, there may be an argument for keeping them secret, but there's not a lot of potential entropy gain in doing so. Kerckhoffs' principle should probably be observed with regard to the cost parameters.

Salt on the side-channel:

Utilizing an APT to deanonymize users by analyzing salt-induced cache side-channels during their login routine is quite a sophisticated attack vector. There are many easier ways for an attacker to determine who's logging into a targeted service. But, it's a valid concern that is relevant in some circumstances. So, avoiding the incorporation of a static user-specific salt in the visitation pattern is a good goal.

EDIT (pursuant comment): All of the benefits and downsides of password-dependent visitation patterns for MHFs which are discussed in the literature also apply to salt-dependence, except for the concerns around leaking password information. This means that there are fewer severe downsides, and the benefits may be enhanced by the fact that salts are better randomizers than passwords. Even though they are not secret once a hash is leaked, they are unknown prior to a hash leak and are unique to each hash, which can prevent attacks reliant on pre-computation. The additional benefits (✅) and downsides (⚠️) include:

✅ Frustrates attempts to optimize attacker hardware such as ASICs and FPGAs.

✅ Resists generic attacks which reduce the attacker-server cost ratio across various metrics, and which appear to reduce the ideal MHF complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ from an exponential factor reduction for data-independent schemes $\mathcal{O}(n^{2 \cdot \Delta})$, with a theoretical max1 of $\mathcal{O}\left(n^{2-\log_n\left(\frac{1}{\log_n({2})}\right)}\right)$, to a multiplicative factor2 reduction for data-dependent schemes $\mathcal{O}(n^2 \cdot \Delta)$ where $0 < \Delta < 1$ and values of $\Delta$ are similar across resilient schemes of both categories such that $\Delta \not\lt \frac{3}{4}$.

⚠️ The increased per-block latency due to randomized accesses.

⚠️ Also more difficult to optimize in honest implementations.

⚠️ Side-channels which can deanonymize users during login.



An advanced idea which I haven't seen discussed anywhere, would be to create a visitation pattern algorithm which can be homomorphic in the choice of salt. That way it might be possible, during each log in, to choose a salt with a specific structure randomly from a subset of the set of possible salts, such that the visitation pattern appears unique and random through side-channel analyses, but which derive the same final result as if a static salt were used.




Conclusion:
So, to sum up. Find as much static public and non-user-specific context and other information as is possible, and provide an interface to accept them all. It'd be good to combine all possible information together in an initial hash that is kept secret and which doesn't induce side-channels. The derivation of a visitation pattern from all public, non-user-specific information would also be best at preventing globally effective pre-computation attacks across all services. But, ideally, new effective and efficient ways would be developed to include secret information as well in visitation patterns, such that they always appear unique and random while still being able to derive deterministic results.

 1. Algebraic re-write of $\mathcal{O}(n^2/\log(n))$ to highlight impact on exponent of generic iMHF attacks linked in [§ 1.6 ¶ 1] to [AB16]. I also reference early work Space Bounds for a Game on Graphs.
 2. A generic 1-pass (random access) dMHF is shown in [§ 5 ¶ 5 Table 3.] to be (.75, AT & TM)-secure, meaning they shouldn't run cheaper than by a factor of $1\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{.75}$ eg. $\Delta \ge \frac{2}{3}$.

Thanks for your answer. I think the context string idea is very interesting and could be made into a separate parameter, although you end up with lots of parameters for the user (memory size, iterations, parallelism, key/pepper, associated data, and now context). It might also need to be restricted in length for performance reasons. Associated data being optional, context being mandatory. The only thing bothering me with this answer is that it doesn't acknowledge the potential positives of using the salt, which is what's not being discussed online.
